# как добавить маску на форме обратной связи?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.
Данные с формы обратной связи приходят с помощью бота в телеграм. И когда приходит сообщение с номером его неудобно скопировать, так как юзер может вписать с "+" или с "8"
Помогите добавить маску что в input было вбито начало номера "+375".

```html
<input name="phone" type="tel" class="contact-form__input contact-form__input_phone" placeholder="Телефон">
```

Что необходимо добавить в js?

Comment: А не проще, сделать константу +375, а в инпут просить вводить пользователя только остаток номера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто надо чтобы значение `input`-а начиналось с `+375`, то можно просто выставить это значение с самого начала, а потом слушать изменение значения

Сейчас стоит всего одна проверка - начинается ли строка с `+375`, если нет, то заменяем значение на старое значение, а если да, то заменяем старое значение на новое.

Проверки дальше можно ставить на свой вкус, в целом думаю идея понятна

```js
const phone = document.querySelector('#phone');
const phoneStart = '+375';

phone.value = phoneStart;

let phoneOldValue = phone.value;

phone.addEventListener('input', () => {  
  if (phone.value.startsWith(phoneStart)) phoneOldValue = phone.value;
  else phone.value = phoneOldValue;
})
```

```html
<input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" class="contact-form__input contact-form__input_phone" placeholder="Телефон">
```

###### P.S. Есть одна проблема (если, конечно, это проблема) при попытке изменить начало строки, курсор перемещается в конец строки

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='phone']").mask("+375 (99) 999-99-99");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input name="phone" type="tel" class="contact-form__input contact-form__input_phone" placeholder="Телефон" value="+375">
```

Comment: Вы можете улучшить ваш ответ, добавив описание